# Modification of Outliers

Tags: bayesian, outliers, small-sample

I have a practical / applied statistics question.  I'm dealing with a specialized dataset with a very small sample (i.e. n < 10).  In the sequence of observations, it is possible that a new observation is an extreme.  However, instead of "removing" the outlier, I'm wondering if there is a way to "adjust" the value to bring it more in line with the rest of the data.  I'm looking into Bayesian methods to accomplish this, but just thought I would ask if there are any good approaches and/or ideas that work for applied / industrial settings.

Comment: What’s wrong with the observation being extreme?

Comment: it could represent measurement error.  a subject matter expert would "know" it is an outlier or uncharacteristic of the data.  But due to the context and how the data is collected, removal of the data point(s) is not an option.

Comment: I see a lot of methods involving "mean replacement" or "median replacement"; or interpolation... just wondering if there is a better approach

Comment: @logisticregress you say a subject matter expert would know that it is an outlier.  Do you know that it is an outlier or are you speculating? Has a subject matter expert said its an outlier? Is the outlier representative of an event, such as an industrial machine breaking?

Comment: Yes, it is more akin to a mis-calibrated machine sensor reading.   But for all intents an purposes, if we have 4 chances to measure and 3 are good, but the 4th seems ridiculous or sensor error, but down-stream industrial processes are dependent on having 4 "correct" readings, then we need to bring the 4th measurement inline with what could be reasonably expected.  and in this example, you cannot just re-measure 4 times after calibrating... we would just do that if it were possible.   :)

Comment: I guess, with a huge dataset I wouldn't really have an issue.  The problem I have is with the ridiculously small sample in this applied setting.  Here's an example of sensor output:  [12.3456, 11.2348, 12.8751, 56.234]  that last one is a problem...

Comment: is the 'problem' with 56.234 that it's obviously too big on its own, or that it's so much larger than 12.8751? // In a different setting, 98.3" on  its own is hard to believe as a person's height; but along with 63.1, 65,5, 64.2, even 72.8 might seem questionable.

Comment: good question, Bruce (and Dave!).  Yes the issue is that it's so much larger than the 3 prior, but not so large as to be impossible... just very very unlikely.  which might suggest something more akin to mean/median replacement, or upper quartile threshold replacement, etc.

Comment: here's an interesting paper I found, btw:  https://www.ufs.ac.za/docs/librariesprovider22/mathematical-statistics-and-actuarial-science-documents/technical-reports-documents/teg451.pdf?sfvrsn=fefab121_8

Comment: "But due to the context and how the data is collected, removal of the data point(s) is not an option" I think one would need more information on the context and how the data is collected and to which end, in order to see, which option might be better or best.